# how to get one random key from 3 dictionaries or more in single time

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get one random key from my 3 dictionaries in one single attempt.

I have tried the code thrice in one line but that is giving me three different randomly generated values.

```
import random
print("Welcome to Blackjack(21) Card Game!")
backjack = 21
number_cards_points = {"2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9}
face_cards_points = {"J":10, "Q":10, "K":10}
acis_cards_points = {"A":1, "A":11}
print(random.choice(list(number_cards_points)))
```

I expect one single value of key from these three dictionaries.
I am a beginner if you have some advanced method to make it happen please do share with me.
Thanks

Comment: `{"A":1, "A":11}` won't work because you can't have duplicate keys in a dict in Python.

Comment: okay, how can i perform the same action i stated  above after removing the duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

Merge all the `dict`s (preserve the order in which you want overriding to work). Then use `random.choice` on the `items` list.

```
import random
print("Welcome to Blackjack(21) Card Game!")
backjack = 21
number_cards_points = {"2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9}
face_cards_points = {"J":10, "Q":10, "K":10}
acis_cards_points = {"A":1, "A":11}
print(
    random.choice(
        list({
             **number_cards_points, 
             **face_cards_points, 
             **acis_cards_points
             }.items()
         )
     )
)
```

Comment: thanks it worked but why did you put ** before the dictionaries, could you please explain this to me.

Comment: PEP 448 - dictionary unpacking to create another dictionary. Standard since Python3.5+ https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to make another list and draw from it instead:

```
number_cards_points = {"2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9}
face_cards_points = {"J":10, "Q":10, "K":10}
acis_cards_points = {"A":1, "A":11}

import random

cards = "2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 J Q K A".split() 
# or use
# cards = list(number_cards_points) + list(face_cards_points) + list(acis_cards_points)

key = random.choice( cards )

print(key, number_cards_points.get(key, 
               face_cards_points.get(key, 
                   acis_cards_points.get(key))))
```

Output:

```
5 5

K 10

3 3

J 10

9 9
```

---

The `number_cards_points.get(rnd,face_cards_points.get(rnd, acis_cards_points.get(rnd))))` looks through all your dictionaries until it finds the correct one providing the value for the drawn key